# MKNetworkEngine doesn't fire its methods

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, mknetworkkit, mknetworkengine

I'm trying to load a set of images from a web service to a `UICollectionView` and I'm using `MKNetworkKit` to handle the networking operations.

This is bit a of a strange problem because it works in one scenario and doesn't in another. Please bear with with me, this is bit of a long post.

I have a simple storyboard app with a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` embedded as its main view (*Can't use `UICollectionViewController` due to a UI change I'm gonna do later*).

I have created a class which is a subclass of `MKNetworkEngine` to handle the method to retrieve the images from the web service.

**ImageEngine.h**

```
#import "MKNetworkEngine.h"

@interface ImageEngine : MKNetworkEngine

typedef void (^ImagesResponseBlock)(NSMutableArray *imageURLs);

- (void)allImages:(ImagesResponseBlock)imageURLBlock errorHandler:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock;

@end
```

**ImageEngine.m**

```
#import "ImageEngine.h"

@implementation ImageEngine

- (void)allImages:(ImagesResponseBlock)imageURLBlock errorHandler:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock
{
    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:@"All_Images.php"];

    [op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
        [completedOperation responseJSONWithCompletionHandler:^(id jsonObject) {
            imageURLBlock(jsonObject[@"Images"]);
        }];
    } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
        errorBlock(error);
    }];
    [self enqueueOperation:op];
}

- (NSString *)cacheDirectoryName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *cacheDirectoryName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeImages"];

    return cacheDirectoryName;
}

@end
```

In the view controller class with the collection view,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GridViewController.h"
#import "ImageCell.h"

@interface GridViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedImageUrl;

@end

@implementation GridViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ApplicationDelegate.imageEngine allImages:^(NSMutableArray *images) {
        self.images = images;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"MKNetwork Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.images.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *thisImage = self.images[indexPath.row];
    self.selectedImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://toonmoodz.osmium.lk/", thisImage[@"image"]];
    [cell.imageView setImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.selectedImageUrl]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

This works just fine. The images load as expected.

Then I did a small UI upgrade to the app using [MBPullDownController](https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController). It simply adds a table view under the collection view. No changes to the networking code. Just a new subclass of `MBPullDownController` to embed the collection view and the table view in the main view controller.

But when I do that, the images don't load at all. I put a breakpoint inside the methods of the ImageEngine class to see if they get fired but it never comes to that. (The weird thing is this code actually worked fine just this morning. Now it doesn't and I have absolutely no idea why). It doesn't throw any errors or warnings either.

I have uploaded two projects demonstrating this issue so that it'll be easier for others to understand. If anyone can help me out, I'd be really grateful. I've been pulling my hair out for the past few hours on this.

[Source](http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/15701319/file.html) of the version that's **working correctly**.

[This](http://www24.zippyshare.com/v/53919688/file.html) is the source of the project that is with the issue. (*When you run it, it'll show a blank white view. It looks like a plain view but it is the collection view. I loaded up a set of local images to see if its working and it does*)

Thank you.

Comment: It's normal to show a blank view because there is no collection view or a "MKNetworkEngine" (at least in the second link "with the issue".

Comment: There is a collection view. [See](http://i.imgur.com/RKHcb8a.png). The bottom two views are loaded in to the top view controller programatically using storyboard IDs. And the `MKNetworkEngine`'s subclass is called ImageEngine in the project.

Comment: @TonyMkenu Oh Wait! You're right. I had uploaded a wrong project. Thanks for noticing that. Link updated.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Sorry about that. I updated the link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set breakpoint in `GridViewController` in `viewDidLoad` method, after executing `po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.imageEngine"]` in console I see that `imageEngine` property is equal to nil.

It looks like `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is being executed after `viewDidLoad` in `GridViewController`.

I removed those two lines from your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
self.imageEngine = [[ImageEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"toonmoodz.osmium.lk"];
[self.imageEngine useCache];
```

Then i've added imageEngine lazy loader to `AppDelegate` and its working http://cl.ly/image/1S172D2e050J

```
- (ImageEngine*) imageEngine {
    if (_imageEngine == nil) {
        _imageEngine = [[ImageEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"toonmoodz.osmium.lk"];
        [_imageEngine useCache];
    }
    return _imageEngine;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, luleq. Your solution works! I also found another method. I moved the portion of the code inside `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` and now it works fine too. Thanks for taking time to resolve it :)